Помогите сделать логи Python, Telebot
расскажите как сделать логи фулл перереписки + действий в текстовом файле?
Написал бота на Python'e и хочу добавить систему логов, но смотря видосы на ютубе нифига не разобрался и выдавало ошибки

странно, вы смогли написать бота, но при этом не можете "сделать систему логов", по видосам с ютуба. Вы точно сами бота писали?

Хаха, сам, я новичок, а про систему логов раньше не думал и не пользовался, смотря видосы на ютубе постоянно либо устаревшее, либо вообще ошибки вылазят. Написать бота с базовыми функциями можно и займёт не так много времени

Примерно что то такое:
def mess(message):
    log = open("log.txt", "w") #Можете посмотреть режимы файлов и выбрать нужный, этот при каждом запуске очищает файл и создает, если его не существует
    log.write(message.from_user.first_name + ":" + message.text + "\n")
    log.close()

Нужные имена пользователей можете посмотреть здесь https://qna.habr.com/q/410443?ysclid=lw84wwbafo552376817
Режимы тут https://pythonru.com/osnovy/fajly-v-python-vvod-vyvod?ysclid=lw8514ozde37321513
